# What does this mean: struct word *nowhead = head[string[start - 'a']];

Tags: c, algorithm

From the C code below I am unable to understand

```
struct word *nowhead = head[string[start - 'a']];
```

Please explain this.

```
struct word **head=NULL;
char string[16384];
start = 0;
...

void insert(char *string, int end, int start)
{
    struct word *nowhead = head[string[start - 'a']]; //this!!
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

UPDATE (From comments)

```
void insert(char *string, int end, int start)
{
struct word *nowhead = head[string[start- 'a']];
int i, j=0, on=0;
char *wtemp;
struct word *temp1, *temp2;

wtemp= calloc(PAROLA, sizeof(char));
if(wtemp==NULL) printf("Error \n");
for(i=start; i<end; i++) {
  wtemp[j]=string[i]; j++;
  }

if(nowhead != NULL) {
  temp1=nowhead ;
  while(temp1!=NULL) {
    if(strncmp(wtemp, temp1->parol, (PAROLA-1))== 0) {
      temp1->occorrenz++; on=1; break;
    }
    else {
      if(temp1->next == NULL) {
        temp2=temp1; }
      } temp1=temp1->next;
    }
  if(on!=1) {
    temp1=malloc(sizeof(struct word));
    strncpy((temp1->parola), wtemp, (PAROLA-1));
    temp1->next = NULL;
    temp1->occorrenze=1;
    temp2->next=temp1; }
  } else {
    nowhead= malloc(sizeof(struct word));
    strncpy((nowhead->parola), wtemp, PAROLA);
    nowhead->next=NULL; nowhead->occorrenz=1;
  }
 free(wtemp);
 }
```

Comment: Which part of that line is causing you trouble?

Comment: Post more code by editing your question, not like that. You also may want to message the users with `@Name`, where name is their names without spaces, otherwise they won't know you have answered their comment.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: The `while(temp1!=NULL) {` loop :: temp1 is not changed inside the loop. (incomplete source?) ALSO (IMHO): use a for() loop instead to make your intentions clear. The surrounding `if(){` is not needed anyway, its condition is the same as the loop condition.

Comment: This the another part of the function
 else
    {
     if(temp1->next == NULL)
     {
      temp2=temp1;
     }
    } 
    temp1=temp1->next;
   }
   
   if(on!=1)
   {
    temp1=malloc(sizeof(struct word));
    strncpy((temp1->parola), wtemp, (PAROLA-1));
    temp1->next = NULL;
    temp1->occorrenze=1;
    temp2->next=temp1;
   }
  }
  
  else
  {
   nowhead= malloc(sizeof(struct word));
   strncpy((nowhead->parola), wtemp, PAROLA);
   nowhead->next=NULL;
   nowhead->occorrenz=1;
  }
  free(wtemp);
}<code>

Comment: GDB says: strncmp (s1=0x60004e700 "ps", s2=0x1 <Address 0x1 out of bounds>, n=256)
at /usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.25-1/newlib/libc/string/strncmp.c:85

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown enough code for context, but the marked line is just accessing an array using an index found in another array.  You could break it down into two operations:

```
char headIndex = string[start - 'a'];
struct word *nowhead = head[headIndex];
```

Comment: And `start - 'a'` is computing the difference between the value stored in `start` and value of the literal character `a` (which, assuming ASCII, is 97).  This might, eg, be used to convert a "Pick option a through z" query result into an array index based on the user's response.

Comment: Probably yes, but more context from the OP would make that more clear, especially given the `char string[16384]` definition above.

Comment: My problem is a Segmentation Fault in a function of my project.
If you wanna see the entire project i can pass this by mail.

Comment: @LorenzoSuiMonti - Then the important thing to do (aside from simply understanding and reviewing your code) is to break the statement down into individual discrete steps, one computation per line.

Comment: @Hot Licks GDB says that the error is in a strcpy because 'enter' in the library

Comment: @LorenzoSuiMonti: usually StackOverflow is ineffective if your program does not work and you don't know why. You must isolate the problem, post a minimal compilable example which exhibits the issue and explain what were you expecting and what you get.

Comment: @LorenzoSuiMonti: An error in `strcpy` usually means that one of the arguments you passed to `strcpy` was garbage.  Use the `up` command to gdb to go up the call stack to figure out who called `strcpy` and what they gave it as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It means set the pointer nowhead to the value in the nested array minus the value of char 'a'